# How to write 1 C program that prints all factors of a number, the sum of the factors, and checks whether it is a perfect number

Tags: c, sum, factors, perfect-numbers

I need to write a program that does all 3 things: print all factors, sum the factors, and check if it's a perfect number.

I am supposed to use only while loops but I couldn't get it to work so I used some For loops instead. Other than that, the main trouble I have is getting the program to check whether the number is perfect or not.

For example, I enter '6' which gives me the factors 1,2,3,6, the sum = 12, but the program thinks '6' is not a perfect number. Please have a look at my code to see where I went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n, f, sum;
    f = 1;
    sum = 0;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The factors of %d are:\n", n);
    //Finding the factors of the given number
    while (f <= n) {
        if (n % f == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", f);
        }        
        f++; //f++ is the same as f = f + 1
    }
    //Finding the sum of the factors
    for (f = 1; f <= n; f++) {
        if (n % f == 0) {
            sum = sum + f;            
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of factors = %d\n", sum);

    //Checking if the number is perfect or not; A number is considered perfect if the sum of it's divisiors equal the number eg 6 = 1+2+3
    for (f = 1; f < n; f++) {
        if (n % f == 0) {
            sum = sum + f;            
        }
    }    
    if (sum == n) {
        printf("%d is a perfect number\n", n); 
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a perfect number\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, then you can step though the code line by line to see what it does, while also watching the variables and their values and how they change.

Comment: Every `for` loop can be converted to a `while` loop, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Look at where you declare f, and where you use it for the first time. About a mile distance. That's bad.

Now look at where you declare sum, and where you use it for the first time. Even worse. And now why your code doesn't work: Look where you think for the second time that you use "sum" for the first time. Except you don't.

By putting the initialisation so far away from the actual use of the variable, you didn't only make your code unreadable, you actually shot yourself in the foot by using sum believing it had a value of zero when it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  statement;
}
```

can be written as:

```
i = 0;
while (i < n) {
  statement;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: you have to be careful about the use of `continue`. in `for` it executes the iterator, in `while` you have to do it yourself.